# How to make assertions with variable text content

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').innerText)
       .eql('Discounted 20% with your subscription');
```

Here the text - `Discounted 20% with your membership`
20% is not constant, it may change to 15% or 19%

how can I "assert" this?

I have tried

```
await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').innerText)
       .eql('Discounted' + 'with your subscription');
```

But doesn’t work

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions.

```
const regexp = new RegExp (your regular expression);

await t.expect(Selector('#elementId').innerText).match(regexp);
```

Refer to this documentation article for more information: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/expect/match.html

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant way to solve this, but one solution I can think of is the following:

```js
const myDiscountList = ["20", "19", "15"];
const innerTextOfMyElement = await Selector('#elementId').textContent;

await t.expect(myDiscountList.some(discount => innerTextOfMyElement === ("Discounted " + discount + " with your membership"))).ok("At least one of the expected discounts should match!");
```

A more elegant way to solve this would probably be making use of regex.